# Create a Mongoose schema with a dynamic key field and test it with input data(json)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Below is my req.body data in Postman:
**

```
{
    "department": "Generic",
    "level": 1,
    "scenario": "During Appointment",
    "question": "Question-1?",
    "answer": "Answer-1."
}
```

**After hitting the API, I will perform the logic as follows:
**

```
const { question, answer, department, level, scenario } = req.body;
const newQuestion = new QA_Model({
    data: {
        [department]: [
            {
                [`Level_${level}`]: [
                    {
                        [scenario]: [
                            {
                                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                                question: question,
                                answer: answer,
                                createdBy: res.locals.decodedToken.payload.name,
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
});
const result = await newQuestion.save();
```

**Now, the above data is stored in the MongoDB database using the Mongoose schema:
**

```
const QA_Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    },
});
```

However, I want to avoid using the mixed type and explicitly mention all field names (department, level, scenario). I attempted to create a schema for dynamic keys(department, level, scenario), but it's not working. **Here is my changed schema:
**

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    question: String,
    answer: String,
    createdBy: String,
});

const scenarioSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    [String]: [questionSchema],
});

const levelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    [String]: [scenarioSchema],
});

const departmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    [String]: [levelSchema],
});

const QA_Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    data: {
        [String]: [departmentSchema],
    },
});
```

**output is
**

```
{
    "data": {
        "_id": "65af56607f1467a0d6c2fd89",
        "function String() { [native code] }": []     //////error (not storing data)
    },
    "_id": "65af56607f1467a0d6c2fd88",
    "__v": 0
}
```

**Expected Output is after storing the database
**

```
{
    "data": {
        "Generic": [
            {
                "Level_1": [
                    {
                        "During Appointment": [
                            {
                                "_id": "65af585947a29da5e5029b40",
                                "question": "Level-1 Question-2?",
                                "answer": "Level-1 Answer-2.",
                                "createdBy": "Palani"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "_id": "65af585947a29da5e5029b41",
    "__v": 0
}
```

How to create dynamic fieldname or key for (department, level, scenario) in the mongoose schema without using mixed type then stored data to the database.

Comment: I generally consider fieldnames-as-data an anti-pattern.  MongoDB indexes will probably not handle that the way you expect, and it will be difficult to query for department using anything other than exact match.